# Changing select box value cannot applied in lables using ajax and jquery

Tags: ajax, laravel, label, jquery-selectbox

In Laravel I have dynamically added multiple select box and labels using jquery. The Select Box values are coming from the database. Using Ajax depending on select box values the label's value (that also come from the database) has to be changed dynamically. It works but all label values are changing. I want to apply values to label only to the specific.
Here I have to attach my code. Thanks in Advance.

**Ajax code for changing select box value and apply results to label**

```
$(document).on('change','.mySelect', function() {
     alert(this.value);
    var unit=this.value;

   var me=$(this);
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  dataType:"json",
  url: "{{URL('newuphist/findunit')}}",
  data:{unit:unit},
  success: function(data){

   me.closest('.mySelect').find("#unitlbl").html(data['unit']);

  },

  error:function(){
   me.closest('.mySelect').find("#unitlbl").html("Error");

  }



});
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <div class="select">

     <select  class="mySelect" name="cat[]" >


        @foreach($data as $item)
           @component('compnew')
              @slot('opt')
               {{$item->diseaseName}}

               @endslot
            @endcomponent

        @endforeach

     </select> &nbsp &nbsp

    @component('comptxt')

    @endcomponent 
    &nbsp &nbsp

      @if(isset($res))

         <label   id="unitlbl" >{{$res}}</label>
         @else
            <label   id="unitlbl"></label>


    @endif     

  <br/>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kindly update your post and copy-paste generated html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add label in same select box div .

```
 e.g
   <div class="select"> 
    <select class="mySelect">
         //code
    </select>
    <label id="myLabel"></label>
   </div>
```

jquery code like

```
 $(document).on('change','.mySelect', function() {
    alert(this.value);
   var unit=this.value;

var me = $(this); // add this 

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  dataType:"json",
  url: "{{URL('newuphist/findunit')}}",
  data:{unit:unit},
  success: function(data){
        me.closest('.select').find("#myLabel").html(data['unit']);

  },

  error:function(){

$(".unitlbl").html("not get");   

  }

});
```

This will work for you dear .

Comment: Thank you  so much for your acknowledgement..But sorry for that it also won't work.

Comment: brother can you please share edited code . because same problem faced by me and i solve by this way .

Comment: me.closest('.select').find("#unitlbl").html("Error"); // please change mySelect to select .

Comment: welcome dear . actually we make mistake in passing class name . again welcome .

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change','select', function() {
    var lbl = $(this).parents('div.select').find('#unitlbl');
    /* TO DO */
});
```

and use `lbl.html()` or `lbl.text()` to update text.

Comment: Thank you so much for your acknowledgement.But its won't work